# Attach async listener to click event

Tags: angular

Is there a way to attach an async click event listener to a button. For instance, if isMobile evaluates to true, I want `(click)="mobileGoogleSignIn"` whereas if it is false, I want `(click)="googleSignIn"`. I can do this already by duplicating the button, but I am wondering if its possible without it.

**View**

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-label btn-google" (click)="googleSignIn()" id="googleLogin">
    <label>
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'google']" size="xs"></fa-icon>
    </label> Sign in with Google
  </button>
```

**Controller**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-button-group',
  templateUrl: './login-button-group.component.html'
})
export class LoginButtonGroupComponent implements OnInit {   
  constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isMobile = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset]);
  }

  googleSignIn() {
    ...
  }

  mobileGoogleSignIn() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Make a generic `(click)="buttonClicked"` and add the condition inside that event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve what you're after would be to use a ternary inside the `(click)` handler.

```
<button (click)="isMobile ? mobileGoogleSignIn() : googleSignIn()" ...
```

Of course you could also achieve this with in single handler and adding the `if (isMobile)` condition:

```
<button (click)="signIn()" ...
```

```
signIn() {
  if (isMobile) {
    mobileGoogleSignIn();
  } else {
    googleSignIn();
  }
}
```

Neither option is great - but will achieve what you're after.

Comment: No,  you will need to subscribe to the observable yourself in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately: "Actions expressions cannot contain pipes".